# How to use UIBezierPath to erarser the freehand-draw?

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath

I have two UIView in app , One can freehand draw on it call pencil view,the other put the Graphics (like image,rectange and so on) call move view

[image]

Now I use white color to erarse the pencil view,but it have some problem the move view will be affected (some area is covered)
[image]

The effect I want to achieve is

[image]

this is my freehand-draw code

```
 override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {


        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)

        UIColor.clearColor().setFill()

        if drawType == MouseStatus.erase{
//            UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke()
            UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke();
            self.path.strokeWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeClear, alpha: 1)
        }else{
            stokeColor.setStroke()
            self.path.strokeWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1 )
        }
        self.img.drawInRect(rect)
        self.path.stroke()

    }


    func setStartPoint(point:CGPoint){

        self.path.lineWidth = drawType == MouseStatus.erase ? CGFloat(lineWidth * 3) : CGFloat(lineWidth)
        self.path.moveToPoint(point)
        self.path.addLineToPoint(point)
        self.pointCount = 0
        self.ctr = 0
        self.pts[0] = point

    }

    func midPoint(point1:CGPoint,point2:CGPoint)->CGPoint{
        return CGPointMake((point1.x+point2.x)/2,(point1.y+point2.y)/2)
    }

    func setMovePoint(point:CGPoint){
        self.ctr++
        self.pts[self.ctr] = point
        self.pointCount++

            if self.ctr == 4 {
                self.pts[3] = CGPointMake((self.pts[2].x + self.pts[4].x)/2.0, (self.pts[2].y + self.pts[4].y)/2.0);
                self.path.moveToPoint(self.pts[0])
                self.path.addCurveToPoint(self.pts[3], controlPoint1: self.pts[1], controlPoint2: self.pts[2])
                self.setNeedsDisplayInRect(self.bounds)
                self.pts[0] = self.pts[3];
                self.pts[1] = self.pts[4];
                self.ctr = 1;
            }

    }

    func setEndPoint(){
        if self.ctr != 4 && self.ctr > 1{
            for index in 1...self.ctr {

                self.path.moveToPoint(self.pts[index-1])
                self.path.addQuadCurveToPoint(self.pts[index], controlPoint: self.pts[index])

            }
        }

        self.drawBitmap()

        self.setNeedsDisplay()
        self.path.removeAllPoints()
        self.ctr = 0
    }
     func drawBitmap(){

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, 0.0);
        if drawType == MouseStatus.erase {
            UIColor.whiteColor().setStroke();
            self.path.strokeWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeClear, alpha: 1)

        }else{
            stokeColor.setStroke();
            self.path.strokeWithBlendMode(kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1)

        }
        let rectpath:UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds)
        UIColor.clearColor().setFill()
        rectpath.fill();
        self.img.drawAtPoint(CGPointZero)
        self.path.stroke()
        self.img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, define Bool, or some indication that you are erasing:

```
let eraserEnabled : Bool = false
```

When you enable eraser, change eraserEnabled = true. This will keep you the state. Now, you can change the path so it actually -ERASES-, by changing the blend mode:

```
// Instead of this
self.path.stroke()

// Do this
self.path.strokeWithBlendMode(erase ? kCGBlendModeClear : kCGBlendModeNormal, alpha: 1.0)
```

Now when you have eraser enabled, you will effectively "cut" out everything, but it will be replaced with clear color, not white, so you will be able to see background, or other elements.

Hope it helps!